# A non table-cell in a display: table behaves different

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

In this [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/xemocubure/edit?html,css,output) example, a particular row which does not have cells but has generic divs, does not consider the table's 100% width even though table width is explicitly specified as 100%.

Is there a way to fix this?

```
<div class="table">
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">cell1</div>      
  <div class="cell">cell2</div>      
  <div class="cell">cell3</div>      
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">cell1</div>      
  <div class="cell">cell2</div>      
  <div class="cell">cell3</div>      
</div>
</div>

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;  
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.section {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Nevermind i got the answer, it was considering it to be within the first td or cell element by default and hence the width of 30% was based on width of first cell of the row

Comment: in `.section` css class you're setting those div's width to `30%`.